# How to query 2 tables in sql server with many to many relationship to identify differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, m2m

I have two tables with a many to many relationship and I am trying to merge the 2 tables in a select statement. I want to see all of the records from both tables, but only match 1 record from table A to 1 record to table b, so null values are ok.

For example table A has 20 records that match only 15 records from table B. I want to see all 20 records, the 5 that are unable to be matched can show null.

### Table 1

### Something | Code#

apple    |  75
pizza    |  75
orange   |  6
Ball      |    75
green    |      4
red         |   6

### Table 2

### date | id#

Feb-15 |    75
Feb-11  | 75
Jan-10 |    6
Apr-08 |    4

### The result I need is

Something | Date | Code# | ID#

---

apple     |   Feb-15  |  75   |   75
  pizza     |   Feb-11 |    75  |   75
  orange   |    Jan-10  | 6 | 6
  Ball   |  NULL   |    75  |  NULL
  green   |     Apr-08  | 4 |   4
  red   |   NULL   |    6   |  NULL

Comment: Why has apple a date of feb-15 and pizze a date of feb-11? Both have the same id and code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm imagining something like this. You want to pair of the rows side by side but one side is going to have more than the others.

```
select * /* change to whatever you need */
from
    (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by "code#" order by "something") as rn
        from tableA
    ) as a
        full outer join /* sounds like maybe left outer join will work too */
    (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by "id#" order by "date" desc) as rn
        from tableB
    ) as b
        on b."id#" = a."code#" and b.rn = a.rn
```

Actually I don't know how you're going to get "ball" to comes after "apple" and "pizza" without some other column to sort on. Rows in SQL tables don't have any ordering and you can't rely on the default listing from `select *...` or assume that the order of insertion is significant.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I don't think the example I provided was good, but you mentioned exactly what I am trying to do which is "pair of the rows side by side but one side is going to have more than the others". I will try the code you provided to see if I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: I originally wrote a query with `group by` before you posted the updates to the question with data. So I ended up changing it and accidentally leaving in the `group by` clause and also not changing the `partition by`part. Fixed not but sorry about that.

Comment: Hey @shawnt00, thanks alot! This was exactly what I needed!  I am new to this site, so I am not sure how to give you credit. Do I just up vote your answer?

Comment: I think when you're new you can't upvote yet. But you can mark it as the accepted answer now and come back to do an upvote later if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

A regular Left-join should do it for you.

```
select tableA.*
     , tableB.*
  from tableA
left join tableB
       on tableB.PrimaryKey = tableA.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: Thank, I have tried the left & right join but its not producing the correct result.  For example if table A has ID# 859 for 5 records and table B has the Code#859 for only 2 records I need to join the 2 tables but make sure that ID # 859 is only matched 2 times with the records in Table B. And the remaining 3 records with ID#859 should show null for Code#

Answer (score 0):

Left outer join
Question changed
Make that a full outer join

```
select table1.*, table2.* 
  from table1 
  full outer join table2  
    on table1.Code# = table2.id#
```

This is probably not a true many to many but I think this is what you are asking for

Comment: Thank, I have tried the left & right join but its not producing the correct result. For example if table A has ID# 859 for 5 records and table B has the Code#859 for only 2 records I need to join the 2 tables but make sure that ID # 859 is only matched 2 times with the records in Table B. And the remaining 3 records with ID#859 should show null for Code#

Comment: @Panthr073 That is a whole lot of detail not in the original question.  See update.

Answer (score 0):

we would need to see the table structure to tell you for sure, but essentially you join on the full key (if possible)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A

JOIN TABLEB B ON
A.FULLKEY = B.FULLKEY
```

Comment: You need a LEFT JOIN, this is an INNER JOIN, and will not give the results the OP wanted.

Comment: Thank, I have tried the left & right join but its not producing the correct result. For example if table A has ID# 859 for 5 records and table B has the Code#859 for only 2 records I need to join the 2 tables but make sure that ID # 859 is only matched 2 times with the records in Table B. And the remaining 3 records with ID#859 should show null for Code#